# SED command use for writing back to the same file

Tags: unix, sed

I have the below code which adds Logger.info line after every function definition which I need to run on a python script which is the requirement.

The only question is this has to be written back to the same file so the new file has all these looger.info statements below each function definition.

e.g. the file abc.py has currently below code :

def run_func(sql_query):

```
return run_func(sql_query)
```

and the code below should create the same abc.py file but with all the logger.info added to this new file

def run_func(sql_query):
    LOGGER.info (''MIPY_INVOKING run_func function for abc file in directory'
    return run_func(sql_query)

I am not able to write the sed in this file to the new file (with same file name) so that the original file gets replaced by same file name and so that I have all the logger.info statements in there.

```
for i in $(find * -name '*.py'); 
do echo "#############################################" | tee -a auto_logger.log
echo "File Name : $i" | tee -a auto_logger.log
echo "Listing the python files in the current script $i" | tee -a auto_logger.log
for j in $(grep "def " $i  | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"(" '{print $1}'); 

do 
echo "Function name : $j" | tee -a auto_logger.log
echo "Writing the INVOKING statements for $j function definition" | tee -a auto_logger.log

grep "def " $i |sed '/):/w a LOGGER.info (''INVOKING1 '"$j"' function for '"$i"' file in sam_utilities'')' 

if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then 
    echo " Auto Logger for $i filename - Not Executed Successfully" | tee -a auto_logger.log
 else 
    echo "Auto Logger for $i filename - Executed Successfully" | tee -a auto_logger.log
 fi 
done
done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown what you are trying to do in form of code. Could you please do mention sample of input and sample of expected output in your post in simple manner, to be honest it is not that clear where you want to use `sed` and how.

Comment: AND we don't really need to see all that code (most likely). Can't you reduce this to a small sample file that needs to be fixed via sed, show the input and required output (as mentioned above). The rest just seems to be getting in the way.  As you heading says *Writing back to the same file* I would expect to see `sed -i '...sed cmds...' file`. If you're using MacOS, then `sed -i'' '....' file`. Good luck.

Comment: When you `grep def $i | sed` you're not going to be able to have sed reconstruct all of file `$i` because you're piping only the lines matching the pattern `def`.

Comment: @shellter On MacOS, you need a space between `-i` and `''` :)

Comment: @CorentinLimier : Right! I thought I typed that, now I don't see that I had any `''` pair. Too early ;-) Thanks for the correction!